# laravel queue in horizon

Tags: laravel, queue, horizon

I need to add only one job in the queue. If a queue has a worker, next job must cancel.
My code:
in Kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('source')->withoutOverlapping()->everyMinute();
```

in Command

```
$count = Redis::lrange('queues:source', 0, -1);

if (count($count) == 0)
    dispatch((new \App\Jobs\Source())->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('source'));
```

in Job

```
public function handle()
{
    dump('job work');
    sleep(2000);
}
```

But I see next jobs in Horizon. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$schedule
            ->call(function () {
                if (Queue::size('source') == 0)
                    dispatch(new TestJob())->onQueue('source');
            })
            ->everyMinute();
```

in Scheduler - it's worked for me